# Error "C2027 use of undefined type" when use std::deque instead of vector

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <deque>
//#include <vector>
#include <map>

namespace xmltree {
    class XMLNode {
        // other fields, methods...
        std::deque<XMLNode> _childs;
...
```

If to define `_childs` as `std::vector<XMLNode>` the code will compile, but with `std::deque` I'm getting error:

> C2027 use of undefined type

What is wrong with std::deque here and how to fix it?

Comment: Obviously shouldn't happen. To learn more I would try to play around with the order of the include files. Another thing I would try is to remove the namespace and see if that helps (not as a permanent solution, just to understand the problem more). Another thing to try is maybe `using` with aliasing for `std::deque` and see if that helps

Comment: The error is correct. At the time of declaration the type `XMLNode` isn't complete. But neither should `std::vector` work (for the exact same reason). Please provide an additional example with `std::vector` that compiles. Preferably make both examples complete.

Comment: @selalerer No, it obviously *should* happen. The only thing puzzling here is OPs claim that the code works with a `std::vector`. Both `std::vector` and `std::deque` need to know the size of the containing type, and at the point where OP declares them, the size isn't known.

Comment: Fail: [std::deque](https://godbolt.org/z/NurkTv), Succeed: [std::vector](https://godbolt.org/z/M8xgij)

Comment: @t.niese That's exactly why it shouldn't work, since XMLNode isn't complete at that point.

Comment: @MaxVollmer, OK! So how to complete it here? I tried to write `class XMLNode;` above all includes - not working... Any other solutions?

Comment: You can't. The class is complete after it's, well, complete. You cannot use it at that point.

Comment: So it seems that since C++17 std::vector allows being instantiated with an incomplete type, if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness requirements. That's why the std::vector example compiles. TIL.

Comment: @MaxVollmer, OK, thank you. I'll use another container

Comment: @MaxVollmer Interesting, I thought that was also true for `deque` in c++17, need to review the specs for that, because gcc does not complain about that, so if that is not valid then it should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Fyi, the posted code works with every version of clang and gcc I've used in the last decade. I can only reproduce this with MSVC (of all ilks regardless of language settings). For gcc, every version down to 4.1.2 (so 12 years ago), all language level settings, consumes this fine. Likewise with clang down to 3.8 regardless of language level request. If you can find a gcc or clang that *doesn't* compile this I'd live to see a link to it.

Comment: @WhozCraig the interesting thing is, this compiles on [godbolt clang 9](https://godbolt.org/z/KNDYQJ) (and locally on my machine) but it does not compile on [wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/) with `clang 9`  (error: `/opt/wandbox/clang-9.0.0/include/c++/v1/deque:277:34: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'xmltree::XMLNode'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does `std::deque` fail**

`std::deque` needs a complete element type. At the point of your declaration `XMLNode` is still incomplete. The usual way around this is to use some kind of (smart) pointer. Pointers to incomplete types are complete. (All pointers have the same size, no matter what they point to.)

So one option would be `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<XMLNode>>`, however depending on your scenario you might want to work with something else.

See [docs for `std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)

**Why does `std::vector` compile**

`std::vector` allows an incomplete element type during instantiation since C++17 under special circumstances. Specifically, it allows it when the allocator for the incomplete type is complete. That seems to be the case in your example. Please note that any usage of the `std::vector` can only be done when the element type is complete, e.g. adding, resizing, accessing elements etc.

See [docs for `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17, `std::vector` (with `std::allocator` as the allocator) could be instantiated with incomplete types. [[vector.overview]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.overview#4):

> An incomplete type `T` may be used when instantiating `vector` if the allocator meets the [allocator completeness requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements.completeness). `T` shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of `vector` is referenced.

And `std::allocator` does meet the allocator completeness requirements. [[default.allocator]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/default.allocator#1)

> All specializations of the default allocator meet the allocator completeness requirements ([[allocator.requirements.completeness]](http://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements.completeness)).

On the other hand, `std::deque` doesn't have such guarantee; it's allowed only for `std::forward_list`, `std::list` and `std::vector`.